# How to disable voice dictation on an iPhone 4S running iOS 5.1 or later?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-dictation

When the keyboard is active on my iPhone 4S (running jailbroken iOS 5.1.1 / 6.1.1), there is a key between the space bar and the numeric entry toggle. This key has a microphone on it and tapping it opens voice dictation.

How do you prevent this key from showing up?

Note that the instructions at http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/04/turn-off-dictation-on-ipad-iphone/ do **not** work; the Keyboard menu does not contain a Dictation toggle.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this. The keyboard detects when you are typing and makes the dictation button activate the space bar.

Comment: @KevinChen, that's accurate if I'm typing quickly. If I'm typing more slowly, when I pause the dictation button is again active.

Comment: It also makes a really annoying noise when this happens, even with my phone on silent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four things that you can try:

### Disable Siri

You can disable Dictation by disabling Siri. Navigate to Settings > General > Siri and turn Siri "Off".

### Update PList File

However, understandably, you may want to use Siri, and since you have a jailbroken phone, this appears possible by editing a .plist.

As per [this MacRumors post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1313328), edit the file `/User/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboard.plist`. Edit it to add the following lines inside of the `<dict>` block:

```
<key>DictationOnSpaceKey</key>
<false/>
```

### Update a different file

Using iFile, edit the file /Users/Library/ConfigurationProfiles/UserSettings.plist

Set `restrictedBool > allowDictation > value` to Off or false. It should look like this:

```
<key>allowDictation</key>
<dict>
  <key>value</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
```

### Install "NoDictation"

[NoDictation](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/01/nodictation/) is a free jailbreak tweak available from the BigBoss repos (available by default on most iOS jailbreaks). If neither of the previous options work, it may.

Comment: @corvec, Interesting. What about post #11 (the last one, and by Intell) on the post that I linked to? Does that work? EDIT: I see you found that before my comment. Let me know what happens.

Comment: @corvec, have you looked in (Restrictions) Parental Controls? I can't look myself this moment but I suppose it's possible that functionality could be disabled in there.

Comment: @corvec, Try enabling restrictions, set a password **you will remember**, and then see if Dictation is in there. I doubt it is but it is worth looking. It's looking like Dictation and Siri are +/- one entity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7139/discussion-between-corvec-and-bassplayer7)

Answer (score 2):

Settings > General > Keyboard > Enable Dictation - Switch it to off.

Comment: Per the OP's question, they are not seeing the setting you reference in your answer.

Comment: Sorry tubedogg-I see that now. Sorry. I just did that though, and it worked for me. Go figure. :)

Comment: As of iOS 8.1 on an iPhone 6+, those instructions work - so that's something, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Siri is the only way I can think of. Go to Settings > General > Siri > slide the switch to Off